# ColdFusion 9 Upgrade: Illegal target of jump or branch

Tags: coldfusion, jrun

I am working on upgrading our codebase from MX7 to 9. I have the Developer Edition of 9 installed on my 10.6 Mac with MAMP Pro 1.9 to verify everything works before we buy upgrade licenses. Many things work just fine. But on several pages I am getting an error that I simply cannot explain. I have gone over the erroring page, report_list.cfm, and its caller, questions_dsp_form.cfm, with a fine-toothed comb, but there's nothing out of the ordinary. I know there used to be an issue with large code files, but that was supposed to be fixed back in version 6! How do I fix this error? We can't upgrade until this is solved!

Here's the complete error message from the console:

```
[Local CF Dev]:07/01 13:44:01 Error [jrpp-11] - (class: cfreport_list2ecfm1269447122, method: _factor0 signature: (Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter;)Ljava/lang/Object; ) Illegal target of jump or branch The specific sequence of files included or processed is: /Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager/index.cfm''
[Local CF Dev]:Exception thrown by error-handling template:
[Local CF Dev]:coldfusion.runtime.EventHandlerException: Event handler exception.
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:288)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:338)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:27)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFil ter.java:28)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilt er.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
[Local CF Dev]:Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: cfreport_list2ecfm1269447122, method: _factor0 signature: (Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter;)Ljava/lang/Object; ) Illegal target of jump or branch
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.newInstance(TemplateClassLoader.java:552 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:191)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:355)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391._factor97(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcso ft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:1658)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391._factor104(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcs oft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:666)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft /surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm615888148.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager /data/overview/index.cfm:35)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960._factor37(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymana ger/data/index.cfm:618)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960._factor38(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymana ger/data/index.cfm:15)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/data/index.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor40(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:468)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor52(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:467)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor12(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor55(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:447)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor14(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor56(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:257)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager/ index.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfApplication2ecfc1705547767$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(/Users/dlaughland/Worksp ace/abcsoft/Application.cfc:215)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:490)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:336)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:280)
[Local CF Dev]:    ... 29 more
[Local CF Dev]:07/01 13:44:01 error ROOT CAUSE:
[Local CF Dev]:coldfusion.runtime.EventHandlerException: Event handler exception.
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:288)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:338)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:27)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFil ter.java:28)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilt er.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
[Local CF Dev]:Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: cfreport_list2ecfm1269447122, method: _factor0 signature: (Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter;)Ljava/lang/Object; ) Illegal target of jump or branch
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.newInstance(TemplateClassLoader.java:552 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:191)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:355)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391._factor97(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcso ft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:1658)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391._factor104(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcs oft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:666)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft /surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm615888148.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager /data/overview/index.cfm:35)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960._factor37(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymana ger/data/index.cfm:618)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960._factor38(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymana ger/data/index.cfm:15)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/data/index.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor40(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:468)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor52(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:467)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor12(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor55(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:447)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor14(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor56(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:257)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager/ index.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfApplication2ecfc1705547767$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(/Users/dlaughland/Worksp ace/abcsoft/Application.cfc:215)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:490)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:336)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:280)
[Local CF Dev]:    ... 29 more
[Local CF Dev]:javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE:
[Local CF Dev]:coldfusion.runtime.EventHandlerException: Event handler exception.
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:288)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:338)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:27)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFil ter.java:28)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:53)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilt er.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
[Local CF Dev]:Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: cfreport_list2ecfm1269447122, method: _factor0 signature: (Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter;)Ljava/lang/Object; ) Illegal target of jump or branch
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
[Local CF Dev]:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.newInstance(TemplateClassLoader.java:552 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:191)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.setTemplate(IncludeTag.java:355)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391._factor97(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcso ft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:1658)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391._factor104(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcs oft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:666)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfquestions_dsp_form2ecfm1275038391.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft /surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm615888148.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager /data/overview/index.cfm:35)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960._factor37(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymana ger/data/index.cfm:618)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960._factor38(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymana ger/data/index.cfm:15)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm2141950960.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/data/index.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor40(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:468)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor52(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:467)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor12(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor55(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:447)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor14(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752._factor56(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanage r/index.cfm:257)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfindex2ecfm13605752.runPage(/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager/ index.cfm:1)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
[Local CF Dev]:    at cfApplication2ecfc1705547767$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(/Users/dlaughland/Worksp ace/abcsoft/Application.cfc:215)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:472)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:405)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:368 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:55)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:321)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:220)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:490)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:336)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:88)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:280)
[Local CF Dev]:    ... 29 more
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilt er.java:70)
[Local CF Dev]:    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
[Local CF Dev]:07/01 13:44:01 error (JRun Service: ProxyService [jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService@2ff55105]) JRunPRoxyServer.invokeRunnable:
[Local CF Dev]:java.lang.IllegalStateException
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.getWriter(JRunResponse.java:205)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.sendError(JRunResponse.java:597)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:328)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
[Local CF Dev]:java.lang.IllegalStateException
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.getWriter(JRunResponse.java:205)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunResponse.sendError(JRunResponse.java:597)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:328)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320 )
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
[Local CF Dev]:    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: What's the code that you're actually calling to get this error?
I can see you're calling cfreport, but that is as good as it gets

Comment: It's not actually using cfreport; the page is called report_list.cfm and cfreport_list2ecfm1269447122 is what it's called after becoming a Java class. The code that triggers this error is a regular ol' cfinclude.

Comment: Let me revise that: report_list.cfm never actually executes. Its caller, questions_dsp_form.cfm, is doing a cfinclude of report_list.cfm, and that line is what's throwing this error.

Comment: It looks from the error like you're stuck in some kind of loop care of the code on line 1658 of "/Users/dlaughland/Workspace/abcsoft/surveymanager/data/overview/questions_dsp_form.cfm", because the same sequence of files is included 3 times before you hit the "Illegal target of jump or branch" error somewhere in the index.cfm

Comment: Do you have a custom error page in place? If you do, try renaming that so you can see Coldfusion's default error - from the second line, it looks like an exception is thrown but the error handling template also has an error.

Comment: I'm with @eapen, try removing the custom error handler if you have one, the second line seems to indicate you do.  [Local CF Dev]:Exception thrown by error-handling template:

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when the body of a if statement is simply too long (hundreds of lines.
From

[Local CF Dev]:Exception thrown by error-handling template:

I'd also suggest simplifying your error handler till you find the pit that brakes it.

Answer (score 0):

This "Illegal target of jump or branch" issue crops up every now and then, seemingly always for a different tag or line of code. As far as I know, it means that your version of Java is too old.

[This was the first time I ran into it](https://github.com/atuttle/Taffy/issues/248), and updating from Java 1.6.0_14 to 1.6.0_75 resolved it then.

As of 19 November 2014, these are the [supported Java versions for ACF 9, 10, and 11](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/which-jdk-is-supported-with-coldfusion-9-10-and-11):

> **ColdFusion 11**
>
> - Update 3 and later: JDK 8
> - Update 2 and earlier: JDK 7
>
> **ColdFusion 10**
>
> - Update 14 and later: JDK 8
> - Updates 8-13: JDK 7
> - Update 7 and earlier: JDK 6
>
> **ColdFusion 9.0.2**
>
> - CF 9.0.2 Cumulative Hot Fix 1: JDK 7**
> - If no CF hot fixes applied: JDK 6
>
> **ColdFusion 9.0.1**
>
> - Cumulative Hot Fix 4: JDK 7 **
> - Cumulative Hot Fix 3 and earlier: JDK 6
>
> **ColdFusion 9.0**
>
> - Cumulative Hot Fix 3 and later: JDK 7**
> - Cumulative Hot Fix 2 and earlier: JDK 6
>
> **JDK 1.7 is only supported on Mac OS X 10.7.3 and later. See this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html) for more details. ColdFusion 9.0.X does not support Mac OS X 10.7. Therefore, Cumulative hot fix 1 does not certify ColdFusion 9.0.X with JDK 1.7 on Mac OS X.